# PyWinAuto type_keys() not giving space between words

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am trying to make a voice typing program in Python using pywinauto. First I recognized the speech using SpeechRecognition module and converted the recognized speech in string and then used the `type_keys()` method to type the string in notepad.

Here is the code:

```
from pywinauto import application
import time
import speech_recognition as sr

app = application.Application()
app.start("Notepad.exe")

def type_keys_in_notepad():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = r.listen(source)


    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        content = r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-in")
        print(content)
        content_str = str(content)
        app.Notepad.edit.type_keys(content_str)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

type_keys_in_notepad()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to add `app.Notepad.edit.type_keys(content_str,with_spaces=True)`

This will help to include white spaces

If you don't include `with_spaces=True` Space will be ignored

Comment: @Raghav did you get a chance to try this ?

Comment: I had a script that typed the windows path of a file as a string in a open dialog window, worked fine for about 6 months, (haven't updated any dependencies, only updated VS Code, so not sure if it's something about that) but now it suddenly started to type the path without spaces. Adding `with_spaces=True` to `.type_keys()` fixed it.